# Algorithm for grouping users by their quiz answers

Tags: algorithms

Let's say I have a cluster of users that I want to group to *N* groups by the similarities of their quiz answers. 
Questions have predefined answers with value of a letter (a, b, c, etc.).
My criteria is to split users into groups based on how similar their answers values are.

Is there an algorithm for that?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What type of questions are these, what criteria are you looking for separating them into groups, etc.

Comment: Updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to get better answers if you post in stats.stackexchange or datascience.stackexchange.

Anyway, here's a very simple method to get you started:

Assume you have $m$-questions and $n$ users which you want to cluster into $N$ groups.

For user $i$, let $x_i = (x_{i1},\dotsc,x_{i2}) \in \{a,b,c,d\}^m$ be the vector corresponding to the answers he gave, i.e. $x_{ik}$ is the answer he gave to the $k$-th question.

You now essentially want to assign a distance between two users. One way to do so is the Hamming distance:

$$d(i,j) = \sum_{k=1}^m \mathbf{1}_{\{x_{ik} \neq x_{jk}\}} $$

Once you have a distance matrix $(d(i,j))_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ there are many methods you can use to cluster the users, for example you could use 
   [Hierarchical clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering).